# Prove a given inequality involving a function's antiderivative

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, inequality

Consider the function $f : \left( 0, \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \frac{\cos x}{x}$ and $F$ an antiderivative of $f$. Prove that:
$$F\left(\frac{e}{3}\right) + \ln3 < F\left(\frac{e}{2}\right) + \frac{13}{8}$$

All I figured out so far is that $f$ decreases, since $\cos$ decreases and $x$ increases on the given interval. I don't know how to proceed.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(x)>0$ for $x\in(0,\pi/2)$, $F$ increases, so $F(e/3)\leq F(e/2)$. Moreover, $\ln(3)<\frac{13}{8}$. Adding both sides  of these inequalities gives the desired result.